# how to read keyboard state outside of keyboard event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to read keyboard state outside of a keyboard event handler? Specifically, I need to check if the shift key is down during page load. I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

There is no querying of keyboard state in JavaScript. Wish there was. You have listen to events and track state yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to work when you're holding the shift key down but it will work on subsequent keypresses. You could unbind it after the first keypress but this also means that it will run even after the page has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.shiftKey)
            alert("Shift was held");
    });
});
```

Comment: only problem with this is he said he wants it during page load, and your code won't get run till the page is loaded.  So the event won't be defined till the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my library KeyboardJS. It has a method called .getActiveKeys() which will tell you what keys are active. The library is really for binding to keys and key combos in a common sense way.

I would suggest using the event binding.

```
KeyboardJS.bind.key('shift', function(){
    //logic on key down
}, function(){
    //logic on key up
});
```

Note that you can do complex things too such as shift + z + x or z + x + c. This will fire if shift, z, x are pressed together, or z, x, c are pressed together.

```
KeyboardJS.bind.key('shift + z + x, z + x + c', function(){
    //logic on key down
}, function(){
    //logic on key up
});
```

You can read what keys are pressed outside of an event callback like this

```
var activeKeys = KeyboardJS.getActiveKeys();
```

Hope that helps,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Stolen and improved from Marko's answer.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.shiftKey)
        alert("Shift was held");
});
```

simply removed the $(document).ready, since you want it while page is loading, not after.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the solution I was hopping for but here's a workaround relying on events:

```
var shiftKeyState = false;
var ctrlKeyState = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).bind("keydown keyup click", function (e) {
        shiftKeyState = e.shiftKey;
        ctrlKeyState = e.ctrlKey;
    });    
});
```